# How to have exposed filters not displayed on search results

Tags: views, search

This is hard to explain so I'm attaching an image.

When someone clicks on a filter to search for something, I would like the resulting page to show results but not the filter. Maybe simply a link like "back to search".

Or possibly a small search box, like basic search but not every filter.

[image]

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6?

Comment: check this http://drupal.org/node/1100550

Comment: I'm using drupal 7. But I can't figure it out still, this is what I did:  1.  add a view with exposed filters to search and create a block for it, 2. create a view with no filters but fields and make a block for it. How can I have the search block display only the results pages but not itself?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple to do with a little coding:

First create a "Display output" template inside your theme folder that will only target the relevant view (check options using "Theme: Information" bottom right under "Advanced" when you are on your view administration page). Copy the contents of "views-view.tpl.php" inside the file and clear the caches.

After that modify the original filter output:

```
<?php if ($exposed): ?>
  <div class="view-filters">
    <?php print $exposed; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to what you need:

```
<?php if ($exposed): ?>
  <div class="view-filters">
    <?php if (!isset($_GET['something'])): ?>
    <?php print $exposed; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php print l(t('Back to search'), $_GET['q']); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You will just have to replace "something" inside that $_GET to a value that is actually used in your filters (check the URL when you have a search performed - it will look like `example.com?something=value1&somethingelse=value2`). Since views adds all the filter keys to the URL when a search if performed you can pick any of them.

Comment: Hi there, tried that but not working for me...I pasted this into my view-view.tpl.php <br/>    <br/>

Comment: <?php if ($exposed): ?>   
  <div class="view-filters">
    <?php if (!isset($_GET['may16.localhost:8082/results-page-content-type-results'])): ?>
    <?php print $exposed; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php print l(t('Back to search'), $_GET['q']); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: You'll have to use a single $_GET parameter not the actual URL of the site. In my code example those parameters are `something` and `somethingelse`. Other than that you may also want to use `view-view--myviewname.tpl.php` or similar as the template to just target the relevant view (`myviewname` should be your actual view name).